# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'merge')" Error when Querying with RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm encountering an issue while using Redux Toolkit Query (RTK Query) in my React project. When I attempt to query an endpoint, I receive the following error:

> ```
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'merge') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'merge')
>     at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4722:58
>     at updateQuerySubstateIfExists (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4650:5)
>     at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4719:9
>     at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6933:20
>     at produce (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:166486:17)
>     at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6932:67
>     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
>     at reducer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6913:25)
>     at reducer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7014:14)
>     at combination (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:159738:29)
> ```

I'm expecting to get access to the data from the response. The data is showing in network tab in the response field of that endpoint but unable to access it in console .

Here is my API endpoint setup using RTK Query:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const token = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
export const brokerApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      headers.set('Authorization', `JWT ${token}`);
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    brokerAuthentication: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `/broker/auth`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: { key: id },
      }),
    }),
    brokerTransactions: builder.query({
      query: (brokerAddress) => ({
        url: `/broker-transactions?brokerAddress=${brokerAddress}`,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useBrokerAuthenticationMutation, useBrokerTransactionsQuery } = brokerApi;
```

I have a Redux store set up as follows:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import uiStateReducer from './uiState';
import { brokerApi } from '../query-services/brokerApi';
import { upiProviderApi } from '../query-services/upiProviderApi';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    uiState: uiStateReducer,
    [brokerApi.reducerPath]: brokerApi.reducer,
    [upiProviderApi.reducerPath]: upiProviderApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(
      brokerApi.middleware,
      upiProviderApi.middleware
    ),
});
```

And finally, I'm querying the `brokerTransactions` endpoint in a component as follows:

```js
// Component code omitted for brevity
import { useBrokerTransactionsQuery } from '../query-services/brokerApi';

function Transactions() {
  const brokerAddress = useSelector(
    (state) => state.uiState.userState.brokerAddress
  );

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useBrokerTransactionsQuery(brokerAddress);
console.log(data)//showing undefined 
  // Rest of the component
}
// Component code omitted for brevity
```

Does anyone have any idea why I might be encountering this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Where in the code is a `merge` property being accessed? In the console you should be able to click in the stacktrace to go to `http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4722:58` in the `updateQuerySubstateIfExists` closure. Back track from there until you get into your code.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code I believe the reducerPath should be defined when calling createApi more that once in an application. A possibility is you could be using more than one createApi in your project defaulting the endpoint to 'api', the reason why the error is being returned is it could not identify the endpoint.

Code Reference below from the Redux Toolkit Documentation:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'

const apiOne = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'apiOne',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    // ...endpoints
  }),
})

const apiTwo = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'apiTwo',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    // ...endpoints
  }),
})
```

Here are some helpful resources on the [Redux Tookit Query createApi](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi)

Comment: This works for a closely related error aswell (Cannot destructure property 'merge' of 'definitions[meta.arg.endpointName]' as it is undefined.). For both my creatAPI instances I had the reducerPath set to "api", changing them to different paths fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your store file to see if the api and reducerpath are properly defined.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).